# Browser shows files in source those do not exist

Tags: javascript

[image]

The browser is load these files and it doesn't exist.
For eg: https://api.fineshopdesign.com/cdn/libs/axios/node_modules/form-data/lib/browser.js

I don't know why is this happening.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a file list that comes from a [source map](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/sourcemaps/).

Your browser is executing compiled, compressed JavaScript - meant for optimized loading and execution but not meant for humans to read and debug through. Meanwhile, raw code is readable and logically split but may not be optimized, could be very large, could be comprised of many files, could be written in a different language (e.g. TypeScript).

Source maps are files that bridge the two by mapping the compiled lines to the raw lines so that debugging compiled code makes sense (i.e. browser steps through compiled code, but human sees raw code). Part of this mapping is a list of files, which is what you see here. Depending on how the source map is made (embedded sources vs separate-file sources, [see Line 5 and Line 6 of the format](https://sourcemaps.info/spec.html#h.qz3o9nc69um5)), the actual source file may not exist on the remote server at all.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am new to typescript, this helped me a lot to understand how these all work.